# SQL query acessing multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, crystal-reports

It is working fine if just display the results from a single table.

```
SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Student.EnrolNo,Student.St_Name FROM Student", ceConnection);

SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(command);
DataSet set = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(set, "Student");

ReportDocument document = new ReportDocument();
document.Load(@"C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Student_Scholarship_management2\Student_Scholarship_management2\MainReport.rpt");
document.SetDataSource(set.Tables[0]);

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = document;
```

Now the above code is working fine as it just references a single table however if i use the query below which accesses record from multiple tables

```
SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Student.EnrolNo,Student.St_Name,Campus.C_ID FROM Student INNER JOIN Campus ON Student.Campus_ID=Campus.C_ID", ceConnection);
```

Only those columns get displayed which are from the Student Table. I have tried importing and linking more tables in through the Database Expert but it is of no use. I have verified the query and the resutls are fine and coming through just not getting displayed in crystal reports.

I have added the table in database expert and have added the relevant column in the report designer. Unfortunately its only displaying the data from one table. What could be causing this?

Comment: Which columns from Campus are you wanting to display? Your `SELECT` statement only references Student table columns, and Campus.C_ID which is the same as Student.Campus_ID - which appears in both tables. You're not selecting any columns specifically from the Campus table.

Comment: I just want to display C_ID from Campus Table

Comment: As i said nothing wrong with the query i have verfied the results from the query and they are displaying correctly

Comment: In that case the issue is with the report itself, possibly you are not referencing the new columns in your report or it's cached/not refreshing the data. If the SQL is working and you're seeing all 3 columns, I'd look into the actual report definition. I don't work with Crystal Reports but chances are you need to explicitly add the new column in the report designer (or definition, etc.)

Comment: Yes, Exactly the problem is the report. I have added the table in database expert and have added the relevant column in the report designer. Unfortunately its only displaying the data from one table and i have no idea why ?

Comment: Have you checked the visibility properties on the new column?

Comment: @TTeeple sry if its a stupid question but how can i do that. I am really new to crystal reports.

Comment: @WinCoder Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952313/crystal-reports-make-text-box-visible-true-false

Comment: @TTeeple I can confirm the field is not suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at your set command:

```
document.SetDataSource(set.Tables[0]);
```

To me that seems to be setting only the first table in your DataSet.

I have a similar situation in the app I'm working on and this is my code (which is passing in about 10 tables):

```
var data = new DataSet();

//Do stuff to populate the dataset

report.SetDataSource(data);
```

The final line sets the datasource of your report to be all the tables in the DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

When you call:

```
adapter.Fill(set, "Student");
```

In that moment, the table schema in dataset is built. So, if you fill below with other columns, only the columns from the first fill will be considered. A solution for you would be to replace:

```
SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Student.EnrolNo,Student.St_Name FROM Student", ceConnection);
```

with

```
SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Student.EnrolNo,Student.St_Name, null as C_ID FROM Student", ceConnection);
```

Comment: But i am not using `SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Student.EnrolNo,Student.St_Name FROM Student", ceConnection);` in the first place the sql i want to get displayed is `SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Student.EnrolNo,Student.St_Name,Campus.C_ID FROM Student INNER JOIN Campus ON Student.Campus_ID=Campus.C_ID", ceConnection);`